# Connection refused with client and server inside the same machine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to develop a simple chat.

I tested client and server using netcat. Testing the server:

nc 127.0.0.1 7779

Testing the client:
nc -lvp 7779

Both the tests are sucessfull: server can connect to netcat and client can connect to netcat!
When I tried to run my server and my client together I always got "[Errno 111] Connection refused" although my server is "Listening in: 0.0.0.0:7779"
Whats is happening?

"

Server:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = "0.0.0.0" #ip generico
port = 7779

try:
    server.bind((ip, port))
    server.listen(5) #numero de conexoes consecutivas
    print ("Listening in: " + ip + ":" + str(port))

    (client_socket, address) = server.accept()

    print ("Received from: " + address[0])

    while True:

        data = client_socket.recv(1024) #bote um while True pARA sempre receber dados!
        print("Cliente: ", data.decode("utf-8") )
        client_socket.send(input("Servidor: " ).encode("utf8") + "\n".encode("utf8"))
    server.close()

except Exception as erro:
    print ("Erro: " + str(erro))
    server.close()
```

client:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#client.settimeout(1)

try:
    client.connect(("127.0.0.1", 7779))

    while True:
        data = input("Cliente: ")
        client.send(data.encode("utf8"))
        #print("Cliente: ", data )

        pacotes_recebidos = client.recv(1024)
        print("Servidor: ", pacotes_recebidos.decode("utf-8") )

    client.close()

    #print (pacotes_recebidos.data.decode("utf-8"))

except Exception as erro:
    print ("Conexao falhou")
    print(erro)
```

Comment: Tested your example without any problem.

Comment: @Sraw: I am using backbox Linux and Python Python 3.5.2 . I dont know what is happening!